# Elasticsearch : Query string on field

Tags: elasticsearch

Can someone tell if I am right/wrong to check if title field contains Item

```
curl -XGET "http://localhost:9200/myapp/item/_search" -d'
{
    "query": {
        "query_string": { 
           "query": "title:Item"
        }
    }
}'
```

EDIT

I have a title like this "Economics and statistics"

**This one returns a record**

```
curl -XGET "http://localhost:9200/myapp/item/_search" -d'
{
    "query": {
        "query_string": { 
           "query": "title:*statistics*"
        }
    }
}'
```

**This one does not return anything**

```
curl -XGET "http://localhost:9200/myapp/item/_search" -d'
{
    "query": {
        "query_string": { 
           "query": "title:statistics"
        }
    }
}'
```

**This one does not return anything either (strange)**

```
curl -XGET "http://localhost:9200/myapp/item/_search" -d'
{
    "query": {
        "query_string": { 
           "query": "title:*Economics*"
        }
    }
}'
```

The doc says :

where the status field ***contains*** active

```
status:active
```

Answer (score 1):

```
you can mention a particular field in default_field

{
    "query_string" : {
        "default_field" : "content",
        "query" : "this AND that OR thus"
    }
}

if you want to specify more than one field then 

{
    "query_string" : {
        "fields" : ["content", "name"],
        "query" : "this AND that"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For beginner like me facing issues with ES : Be really careful on how you map / tokenize your data.
"not_analyzed" does not mean what I thought it meant and that lead me to the issue above.

Answer (score -1):

Your query looks good. but you can also achieve same by below query.

```
curl -XGET "http://localhost:9200/myapp/item/_search" -d'
{
   "query": {
      "term": {
         "title": {
            "value": "Item"
         }
      }
   }
}'
```

While looking into elasticsearch query optimizations stuff I found suggestion to avoid to use of `query_string` until it is necessary. also `query_string` is not cached by default.

[Reference Article](http://euphonious-intuition.com/2013/02/five-things-i-learned-from-elasticsearch-training/)

Comment: Thanks Roopendra to pointing me to the fact query_string are not cached, didn't know.
Thing is my query does not work and as I am new to ES I wanted to check if I was on the good path.
Now I need to figure out what's wrong.

Comment: Ok, trying out your query it does not work either. So that must be a problem on my environment. I am 100% sure that I have the word "Item" in a title field.

Comment: Your existing query return some value? also make a try with `curl -XGET "http://localhost:9200/myapp/_search"`

Comment: I edited my post to answer your question of what is returned or not.

Answer (score -1):

```
curl -XGET "http://localhost:9200/myapp/item/_search" -d'
{
    "query": {
        "match": { 
           "title": "statistics"
        }
    }
}'
```

This would be enough if you want to search exact terms(not exact content of the field). Try to avoid the usage of wildcards as it is expensive. For searching with a fraction of word in a field, you have to modify the mapping as of your need.

Check your mapping and see the type of field **title** . If it is not_analyzed, re-index it to be **analyzed**(by default).

Comment: The question is about query_string